# Jooq bind the same parameter multiple times

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have an SQL query that uses the same parameter in several places (the table name changed between the environments prod, stg, dev):

```
String SQL =
select *
from :a_table a
join :b_table b
on a.x != b.x
where a.y not in (select b1.y
                  from :b_table b1
                  where b1.x = a.x)
```

I run this query with Jooq:

```
return dslContext.fetch(sql, param("a_table", ATable.getName()), param("b_table", BTable.getName()));
```

but the parameters are replaced only once, and the query that Jooq runs is (assuming `ATable.getName() = "A"` and `BTable,getName() = "B"`):

```
select *
from A a
join B b
on a.x != b.x
where a.y not in (select b1.y
                  from :b_table b1
                  where b1.x = a.x)
```

is it possible to replace the params in all places without putting it more than once in the `fetch` calli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Bind values

A bind value cannot be a table in SQL. A bind value is a parameter to the SQL query, representing a scalar value, not some syntactic element, e.g.

```sql
SELECT :b1, :b2 + 1 -- Scalar values
FROM t              -- "Syntactic element"
WHERE t.x = :b3     -- Scalar values
```

This isn't jOOQ specific. You (probably) won't find any SQL dialect out there that allows for bind values to be used as tables.

### Templates

If you wish to implement dynamic text based SQL like that, use ["plain SQL templates"](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), e.g.

```java
String sql = 
    """
    select *
    from {0} a
    join {1} b
    on a.x != b.x
    where a.y not in (select b1.y
                      from {1} b1
                      where b1.x = a.x)
    """;

// And then
return dslContext.fetch(sql, ATable, BTable);
```

Assuming `ATable` and `BTable` are of type [`org.jooq.Table<?>`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Table.html). Templates are purely a jOOQ feature. They will be replaced when jOOQ generates SQL prior to passing the generated SQL to the JDBC driver.

See also this blog post for [more information on using plain SQL templates with text blocks](https://blog.jooq.org/using-java-13-text-blocks-for-plain-sql-with-jooq/)